# If condition triggers despite not meeting requirements

Tags: python, if-statement

Hello I am trying to relearn python using turtle with the following code:

```
def move_random(t):
    direction = random.randint(-45,45)
    t.setheading(t.heading() + direction)
    t.forward(random.randint(0,50))
    print(f' {t.xcor()} and {t.ycor()}')
    if (t.xcor() or t.ycor() >= 250) or (t.xcor() or t.ycor() <= -250):
        t.setheading(t.heading()+180)
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
```

`
I am looping this code 250 times.

I want it to change the turtle direction by 180 degrees, if the turtle goes outside the square boundaries which I have set to -250 and 250.
But with this code it changes 180 degrees regardless. Am i doing something wrong in the if condition ? Its the only thing I can think off.
I didn't understand what was going wrong so I started printing the x and y coordinates and switching the <= and >= but it still triggers the setheading after the if statement regardless.

Basically the If condition never returns False even though the values never meet the requirements.

Comment: Example run:
True
 192.57437991526848 and -213.38197997258584
True
 181.68789461328345 and -257.04528765500567
True
 208.64598712178258 and -218.54514157342305
True
 170.03346019505324 and -248.71255386438034

Comment: `if (t.xcor() or t.ycor() >= 250)` is equivalent to `if ((t.xcor()) or (t.ycor() >= 250))` the condition `if (t.xcor())` will be true if `t.xcor()` has a value different of `0`

Comment: Ok I kind of understand, I guess what i wrote is not acceptable syntax for what I'm trying to do.
I wrote it like this:
if ((t.xcor() >= 250) or (t.xcor() <= -250)) or ((t.ycor() >= 250) or t.ycor() <= -250):
and now it works.
Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

Your t.xcor() is never zero, so it is evaluated as True. If you mean `t.xcor() >= 250`, you have to write it.

Answer (score 0):

```
def move_random():
  direction = random.randint(-45, 45)
  t.setheading(t.heading() + direction)
  t.forward(300)
  print(f' {t.xcor()} and {t.ycor()}')
  if (t.xcor() >= 250 or t.ycor() >= 250) or (t.xcor() <= -250 or t.ycor() <= -250):
      t.setheading(t.heading()+180)
      print("True")
  else:
      print("False")
```